Как выносить под-пространства имён по разным файлам?
Всем привет;
Хочу написать пространство имён, а его подпространства вынести в отдельные файлы;
Имеется запись:
#ifndef SPECTRE_HPP
#define SPECTRE_HPP

namespace Spectre
{
    namespace Math
    {
        
    }
} 

#endif SPECTRE_HPP

Как можно перенести пространство Math в другой файл так, чтобы в самом проекте я мог подключить только Spectre.hpp и при этом иметь доступ ко всем его подпространства (Math and other)?
Например (main.cpp):
#include "spectre.hpp"
using namespace Spectre;

int main()
{
    double local_pi = Math::PI;
}


Подключайте в Spectre.hpp эти другие файлы с объявлениями содержимого Math. В чем проблема-то.

Не понимаю как написать

math.h:
namespace Math {}

other.h:
namespace Other {}

spectre.h:
namespace Spectre {
    #include "math.h"
    #include "other.h"
}

Это если нужно иметь возможность включать math, other в другие пространства имён. Но обычно такое не требуется и при разнесении по файлам сразу указывают полностью пространства имён:
math.h:
namespace Spectre::Math {}

other.h:
namespace Spectre::Other {}

spectre.h:
#include "math.h"
#include "other.h"


Второй вариант лучше. Первый - бесконечный источник багов. (Интелисенс такое вряд ли поймет.)
